# Avoiding CheckStyle magic number errors in JDBC queries

Tags: jdbc, checkstyle

I am working on a group project for class and we are trying out CheckStyle.

I am fairly comfortable with Java but have never touched JDBC or done any database work before this.

I was wondering if there is an elegant way to avoid magic number errors in preparedStatement calls, consider:

```
        preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO shows "
                + "(showid, showtitle, showinfo, genre, youtube)"
                + "values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, title);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, info);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, genre);
        preparedStatement.setString(4, youtube);
        result = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

The setString methods get flagged as magic numbers, so far I just added the numbers 3-10 or so to the ignore list for magic numbers but I was wondering if there was a better way to go about inserting those values into the statement.  I also beg you for any other advice that comes to mind seeing that code, I'd like to avoid developing any nasty habits, e.g. should I be using Statement or is PreparedStatement fine? Will that let me refer to column names instead? Is that ideal? etc...

Thanks!

Comment: As a side-note, it would also be useful to know how to avoid magic numbers while retrieving the data too - i.e. `getString()` etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create an utility method which does something like this:

```
public static void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object... values) throws SQLException {
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        preparedStatement.setObject(i + 1, values[i]);
    }
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
setValues(preparedStatement, title, info, genre, youtube);
```

or

```
Object[] values = {
    title, info, genre, youtube
};

setValues(preparedStatement, values);
```

More "best practices" with regard to basic JDBC coding can be found in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that even if you don't use Spring, try using the [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) instead. Take a look at http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-named-parameter-jdbc-template.html for a tutorial on how to use it.